# Using a ref to pass GridView columns to a method

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ref, byref

So I'm working on this VB to C# web application migration and came across an issue that I'm hoping there is an easy work around for. There's a webform that uses the GridView control. In code, it passes the columns collection into a method that adds columns dynamically based on the user, permissions, and environment. So, the columns were passed into the function in VB using ByRef like so:

```
Public Sub PopulateColumns(ByRef ColumnCollection As DataControlFieldCollection)
    'Do something
End Sub
```

Now in C#, I've used the ref keyword, but the columns collection doesn't have a setter. What's my quickest workaround for this? I'm going to be converting this over to a jQuery grid soon so I'm not concerned with best practices, but rather just getting it to work.

Here it is in C#:

```
public void PopulateColumns(ref DataControlFieldCollection columnCollection)
{
    // Something here
}
```

which is called like this...

```
.PopulateColumns(ref EmployeeGridView.Columns)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection is already ByRef, so you do not need the ref argument.

So, <s>unless I'm having a blonde moment</s>, you just have to do:

```
public void PopulateColumns(DataControlFieldCollection columnCollection)
{
    // Something here
}

.PopulateColumns(EmployeeGridView.Columns)
```

Tested and working.

Comment: Not quite sure why it was a ByRef before. Thanks for saving my blonde moment!